# How to display dates in matplotlib x-axis instead of sequence numbers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I am trying to develop a candlestick chart with matplotlib but for some reason, dates are not coming up in the x-axis. After searching in stackoverflow, I understood that the dates need to be converted to float numbers so i converted them as well but still it's not working. New to this python and matplotlib. ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as dts
import matplotlib.ticker as mTicker
from datetime import datetime
my_file=pd.read_csv("C:\\path\\to\\file\\file.csv",sep=",",names=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','AdjClose','Volume'],skiprows=1)
dateseries=[]
for i in my_file['Date']:
    dateseries.append(dts.date2num(datetime.strptime(i,'%Y-%m-%d')))
print(dateseries)
fig,ax1=plt.subplots()
candlestick2_ohlc(ax1,my_file['Open'], my_file['High'],my_file['Low'],     my_file['Close'], width=0.7,colorup='#008000', colordown='#FF0000')
plt.show()
```

Sample data:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume1,Volume2
2017-05-08,149.029999,153.699997,149.029999,153.009995,153.009995,48752400
2017-05-09,153.869995,154.880005,153.449997,153.990005,153.990005,39130400
2017-05-10,153.630005,153.940002,152.110001,153.259995,153.259995,25805700
```

Comment: You need to set the 'Date' to the pandas dataframe index. Try:
my_file = my_file.set_index('Date') after you load the file.  Don't need the dateseries stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Geoff. I tried setting the date as index and it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

In general, you are right about "the dates need to be converted to float numbers". Then to display dates on x-axis, you would need to "convert" them back. If you don't mind using `candlestick_ohlc`, that might be easier for setting the x-axis for your case here:

```
import io

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, DayLocator, DateFormatter
import pandas as pd

s = """Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume1,Volume2
2017-05-08,149.029999,153.699997,149.029999,153.009995,153.009995,48752400
2017-05-09,153.869995,154.880005,153.449997,153.990005,153.990005,39130400
2017-05-10,153.630005,153.940002,152.110001,153.259995,153.259995,25805700"""
my_file = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(s), sep=',', header=0)

my_file['Date'] = date2num(pd.to_datetime(my_file['Date']).tolist())

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
candlestick_ohlc(ax, my_file.as_matrix())
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try this when i reach home.